# How has Okonkwo succeed in resisting the colonizer through word-play in "Things Fall Apart"?

Tags: character-analysis, chinua-achebe, things-fall-apart

In Things Fall Apart, Okonkwo  refuses to speak the language of the colonizer (the white man) , rather he uses his own language (Ibo) to deconstruct the language of the colonizer. So, how has Okonkwo succeed in resisting the colonizer through word-play in "Things Fall Apart" ?